# Lasso Screenings in biglasso package

Tags: regression, lasso, high-dimensional

I am currently using the biglasso package for some simulations. For the biglasso() function, there is an argument called screening. The default screening for lasso is "adaptive". Is adaptive screening for the lasso the same as an adaptive lasso or something else?

Here is the documentation.
https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/biglasso/biglasso.pdf